# How can I check if an audio livestream is active behind a given URL?

Tags: javascript, node.js, audio, live-streaming

I want to build a little script in nodejs which goes through a list of URLs and **checks if there is an audio livestream actually running**.

The URLs can either be direct mp3 livestreams or HLS livestream URLs which link to .m3u files.

How can I do this check in JavaScript? Simply checking if there is no 404 is not enough.

Answer (score 0):

The tricky thing here is that even though the source may be down, the server may still return its buffered data.  In fact, this is very common.  Servers will buffer 20-30 seconds of data or so, and will send that to you on connect.  With HLS, the problem is even worse as usually a large number of HLS segments will be on disk.

You will need to connect and read from the stream, and then have a sort of timer where you determine if you're getting any more data.  You can put this behind your HLS or HTTP progress clients, and handle both the same.  Connect, and begin streaming data.  Every time you receive a chunk of data, note the time.  Periodically check the time between now and when you last received data.  If it's been 20 seconds or so, it's likely that the stream isn't up and running.